# Disallow only spaces after a string - Python 3.3

Tags: python, python-3.3

If `name = 'Steve '`how would I disallow this? But allow `'Steve 2'` and `'Steve'`

This is because I am printing out keys from dictionaries and I don't want confusion between names displayed. Thanks.

Comment: `if name[-1] != ' '`

Answer (score 1):

```
if name != name.rstrip():
    # disallow
```

Comment: You could just as easily use rstrip() to always remove whitespace at the end of a string rather than forcing the user to match convention.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the name before inserting it into the dictionary.

```
# this will remove spaces from both sides of the string
name = 'Steve '.strip()
# this will remove spaces from the right side of the string
name = 'Steve '.rstrip()
# this will remove spaces from the left side of the string
name = ' Steve'.lstrip()
```

You could get fancy and subclass dict.

```
class StrippedKeyDict(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        key = key.strip()
        super(StrippedKeyDict, self).__setitem__(key, value)

>> x = StrippedKeyDict()
>> x['Steve '] = 'data'
>> print(x)
{'Steve': 'data'}
```

Comment: Thanks for the post, it works great on its own but when I use it like this:             `name = str(input("Enter your name: "))
            name=name.strip
            name = name.title()` It doesn't work and comes up with an `AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'title'`

Comment: That's because you're using `name=name.strip` instead of `name=name.strip()`

Comment: Thanks again, I'm such a derp